# Qprocess arguments echo and piping

Tags: c++, shell, process, qt5, qprocess

I am trying to launch a CEC command in my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) under a QProcess.

if i execute in my shell this:

```
echo 'standby 0' | cec-client -s
```

it is working, but if i put it inside a Qprocess with this:

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess;
proc->start("echo",{"'standby 0' | cec-client -s"});
proc->waitForFinished();
```

it is not executing as expecting. Otherwise in my Raspberry Pi is workig well. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What happens differently?

Comment: I do not believe this will work without spawning a shell instead of executing echo. The pipe itself is a feature of the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you cannot run a system command with QProcess, but only a single process. So the workaround will be to pass your command as an argument to bash:

```
process.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "echo 'standby 0' | cec-client -s");
```